# CSS is not showing up when new CSS class is added, but old CSS class is showing up

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So I have been trying to add a new css class to a particular feature on a website. For this feature, it is already connected to an already made CSS class in the style.css by having the css classname inside the div of the feature. However, when I go to create a new css class and add it to the style.css/replacing the classname in div of feature, it does not show up on the website. However, when I use the old class that the feature was connected too and input that name into the div of the feature, the old css shows up. I cleared all my cache and updated the media query. I also restarted my computer, but no luck. I was wondering how to go upon this issue and if anyone had any recommendations?

Thanks!

Here is how my code is right now and which is showing up on site:

```
<div class="water-bottle water-square">.....</div>
```

CSS

```
.water-bottle {
   width: calc(50% - 15px);
   min-height: 15.5em;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   padding-left: 50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-top: 40px;
   padding-bottom: 40px; 
   border-radius: 16px;
   position: relative;
}
```

This is what I change it too and it does not show up:

```
<div class="water-bottle-pop water-square">.....</div>
```

CSS

```
.water-bottle-pop {
   width: calc(50% - 15px);
   min-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 40px; 
   border-radius: 16px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Open your dev tools, go to its settings, and make sure the "disable HTTP cache when dev tools is open" (or similarly named) checkbox is checked. Then reload while keeping dev tools open (which should always be open during dev work anyway =)

Comment: Hi your question is difficult to answer without context, can you post some code here please? Either you need to blast your cache, you have a missing css file, or your classes in that file are improperly formatted.

Comment: My best guess: a caching issue. Try CTRL+F5 after having changed the CSS.

Comment: Hey There @Mike, I tried your method of checking the box and that did not work sadly

Comment: After all, what is the problem I am unable to understand

Comment: The problem is that the css class the div/feature it is connected to currently is showing up. But when I create a new css class in the style.css page and update the className in div where the feature is, it does not show up

Comment: @Gerald, tried doing that but no change sadly

Comment: @JohnStewart Look at the class names properly in CSS and Html

Comment: @JohnStewart otherwise can you share your file with us?

Comment: updated to reflect code above^^^

Comment: remember to look at what you show, and whether that makes sense: what you showed works completely fine on its own, so please show a [mcve] (and running through the MCVE exercise forces you to whittle down your codebase until either the problem suddenly disappeared, or you _really_ have working minimal code. Either way, you're a lot closer to a solution), or this is probably heading to "question closed: not reproducible".

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the comment Mike. I had someone else run the code on their computer with the same exact changes and it shows up for them. So I believe it is a cache issue, but trying to figure it out

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
Both are working well, if you want, you can try running both together.
```

```css
/*.water-bottle {
   width: calc(50% - 15px);
   min-height: 15.5em;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   padding-left: 50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-top: 40px;
   padding-bottom: 40px; 
   border-radius: 16px;
   position: relative;
   border:2px solid red;
}*/
.water-bottle-pop {
   width: calc(50% - 15px);
   min-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 40px; 
   border-radius: 16px;
   position: relative;
   border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!--<div class="water-bottle water-square">.....</div>-->
<div class="water-bottle-pop water-square">.....</div>
```